# PHP not recognising Flash undefined var

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm having a problem with Flash AS3 and PHP 5.3.29
I have a var that I want to pass to PHP. This var will in certain cases be undefined or will have a value.

```
if(!isset($_POST['varName']) || empty($_POST['varName'])){
    $name = ">0";
    }
    else{
        $name = "=".$_POST['varName'];
        }
```

AS3 code:

```
var myVarsReq:URLRequest=new URLRequest(returnQuery);
    var phpMyVarsVar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        myVarsReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        phpMyVarsVar.varName = varName;  //varName = undefined;
        myVarsReq.data = phpMyVarsVar;
        phpMyVarsVar.sendRequest = "getResults";
```

I use Charles to trace the outgoing data from Flash and when the varName = undefined PHP !isset() is not picking it up as not being set. If I force the varName varName = "" then the empty() function picks it up fine. Similarly, if I give the varName a value, varName = 44 it all works fine so what am I doing wrong with isset??

OK, I echo'd the $_POST var both before and after !isset. The $POST var according to Flash Charles and the echo before the !isset was undefined, not NULL "" or "undefined", however PHP is seeing it as isset and not !isset... Why PHP is doing this? I don't know but for anyone experiencing the same issue: - my work around was to force the var as "" empty rather than undefined. Its not graceful or ellegant but it works... I'd still love to know why though!

Comment: Come on guys, someone must have an insight into this - is it me or is it PHP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those hwo are still wondering... After some investigation and assistance from another forum it appears that there is no way that you can send a var that is not set (!isset) from flash to PHP. According to PHP it will always be set one way or another.
My findings: - When myVar is defiend as a number but not given a value

```
sendVartoPHP.varName = myVar:Number
```

is seen by PHP as string(3)"NaN"

```
sendVartoPHP.varName = myVar:int
```

is seen by PHP as string(1)"0"

```
sendVartoPHP.varName = myVar:String
```

is seen by PHP as NULL

```
sendVartoPHP.varName = myVar
```

a 'none typed' var is seen by PHP as string(9)"undefined"

```
sendVartoPHP.varName = ""
```

is seen by PHP as string(0)

```
sendVartoPHP.varName
```

not even setting the var  to be sent (as above) is seen by PHP as NULL

Answer (score 0):

Isset only works if the variable isnt set at all, you probably send an empty or vanName=undefined from action script

maybe just do this

```
if($_POST['varName']=="undefined" || empty($_POST['varName'])){
    $name = ">0";
    }
    else{
        $name = "=".$_POST['varName'];
        }
```

Comment: Thats my point, the variable isn't set, it leaves Flash as undefined... What you suggest is a work around but having read reams on the web isset should throw a true or false. I just wanted to understand this and know why it wasn't working...Is it me!? When I run run it in pure PHP and don't define the $_POST it works great and echos the fact. The moment Flash sends it an 'undefined' var it doesn't work. My current work around is to feed PHP an empty var but I'd still like to get to the bottom of this conundrum. Thanks for your suggestion though..

Comment: Think the problem is AS sends the variable varName=undefined as a string. If you have firebug on firefox installed you can check what postdata the flash script sends

Comment: You have a link i can see  the flash file ?

Comment: Jelle Keizer - The var is set as varName = undefined and NOT varName = "undefined" so in Flash varName is holding no value. When I use Charles Proxy it shows the var as undefined bot NULL or blank so I'm a little confused. Sorry I can't provide you a link as I'm on my internal dev environment...

Comment: I started on this journey because originally I was getting a undefined var $varName in PHP error logs. Thats what prompted me to read up on isset(), unset() and empty() etc. I just couln't get isset to respond to an undefined variable though and hence, here I am

Comment: A Post or Get variable with the value undefined will always be of the data type string.

Comment: Maybe useful to post AS script as well